# split string at vowel + surrounding consonants

Tags: python, string, split, slice

I am new to coding and this is my first try. I want to divide words into syllables from a phonetic language.

Rules to make syllables out of words from a phonetic language:

consider all consonants until the first vowel, consider that vowel.
repeat.

Example:

m**a** - r**i**- **a**

**a** - l**e** - ks**a** - nd**a** - **r**

This is how far I've come :

```
    word = 'aleksandar'
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    for vowel in vowels:

        if vowels in word:

            index_1 = int(word.index(vowel)) - 1
            index_2 = int(word.index(vowel)) + 1

            print(word[index_1:index_2])

        else:

            print(consonants)
```

IDK what is going wrong, please help!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
word = 'aleksandar'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

new_word = ""

for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        new_word += letter + "-"
    else:
        new_word += letter

print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed your code little bit and it works perfectly!!!

```
word = 'aleksandar'
word = list(word)
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
s = ""
syllables = [ ]
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] not in vowels:
        s = s + word[i]
    else:
        s = s + word[i]
        syllables.append(s)
        s = ""
print(syllables)
```

and the output is :

```
['a', 'le', 'ksa', 'nda']
```